# What is the form of general expression (one expression) for the eigenfunctions of discrete and continuous spectra of motion in the Coulomb potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, coulombs-law, orbitals, special-functions

Eigenvalues of motion in the Coulomb potential have a discrete spectrum and a continuous spectrum. The eigenwave functions have the form:
For discrete spectrum radial functions(in mathematica code):

```
Rnl = 2/(n^(l + 2) (2 l + 1)!) Sqrt[(n + l)!/(n - l - 1)!] (2 r)^
  l Exp[-r/n] Hypergeometric1F1[-n + l + 1, 2 l + 2, (2 r)/n]
```

For continuous spectrum radial functions(in mathematica code):

```
Rkl = Subscript[C, kl]/(2 l + 1)! (2 kr)^
  l Exp[-ikr] Hypergeometric1F1[i/k + l + 1, 2 l + 2, 2 ikr]
```

Is there a unified expression for these radial functions? Those one expression describing both the functions for the discrete spectrum and for the continuous one.

Comment: I am a new user, please tell me how to write formulas in the usual way?

Comment: Use Latex code, please. You can easily get a tutorial.on the internet.

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DanielC, thanks! Could you please reply to my comment below?

Answer (score 1):

There is no unified expression, because we simply have two different ordinary differential equations, each with its own set of solutions, according to whether a certain parameter (eventually found to be the spectral value of the Hamilton operator) is either negative or positive. The only common fact is that both ODEs can be solved in terms of confluent hypergeometric functions of real or complex variable. And of course, the general (also called "generalized") eigenstate of the Hydrogen atom (or Hydrogen-like ions) can be expressed according to Dirac as a linear combination of eigenfunctions of the discrete spectrum and of the continuous spectrum. This appears justified because the discrete and continuous parts of the spectrum do not overlap.

Comment: thanks! I asked this because I want to find the energy eigenvalues by the matrix method and use these eigenfunctions as basis functions. But only both functions - for the continuous spectrum and the discrete spectrum - form a complete basis. Therefore, I cannot take one of these expressions and look for energies based on it. Therefore, I would like to have some one expression that would describe the complete set of basis functions.